# find last active element in html

Tags: jquery, html

I want find the last active class of list. I have tried like below. But it return all active class text. the li active class is dynamically added.

```js
alert($('.test li.active:last-child').find('a').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test">
  <li class="active"><a href="">test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">test2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">test3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"> <a href="">test4</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="">test5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/EcZZL/411/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:last-child` represents element that is the last child element of its parent. Since in your example `li.active` is not the last child thus it not worked.

You need to use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector instead of `:last-child` selector.

```
$('.test li.active:last').find('a').text()
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r40yt7ts/)

Answer (score 5):

use [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) or [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('.test li.active:last')
$('.test li.active').last()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with jQuery's [last method](https://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
alert($('.test li.active').last().find('a').text());
```

Or with [the selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
alert($('.test li.active:last').find('a').text());
```

Answer (score 3):

`:last-child` will only take into consideration the hierarchy.

The idea behind this is that you might want a rule such as:

```
li.active:last-child
```

This is stating "Select all `li` elements which have the class `active` and are the last child element".

It doesn't mean the last child element which matches the selector.

---

You can however use jQuery's `:last` or `.last()` to obtain the last element which matches the selector.

```
$('.test li.active:last')

$('.test li.active').last()
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-selector you need is `:last`, as in:

```
$('li.active:last')
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(

    function() {
        $('li.active:last').css('border','1px solid red');
    }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="test">
<li class="active"><a href="">test1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="">test2</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="">test3</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="">test4</a></li>
<li><a href="">test5</a></li>        
</ul>
```

---

**N.B.** Javascript doesn't have a clever computational pseudo-selector like `:last`, so in native javascript you would need to be a little more sophisticated.

The native javascript equivalent of jQuery's

```
$('li.active:last').css('border','1px solid red');
```

is

```
var actives = document.querySelectorAll('li.active');
var lastActive = actives[(actives.length - 1)];
lastActive.style.border = '1px solid red';
```